# Move common mocking code to a separate file containing a Jest manual mock

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

There is a mock I use in many places, so I want to move it into a separate file that can be reused.

I think Jest calls this a "manual mock". However I don't want to use the `__mocks__` convention.

The top of the file being tested:

```
import * as dotenvSafe from "dotenv-safe";
```

The manual mock file:

```
const dotenvSafe: any = jest.genMockFromModule("dotenv-safe");

dotenvSafe.load = jest.fn(() => {     // the function I want to mock
  return {
    error: undefined,
    parsed: [],
  };
});

export default dotenvSafe;
```

At the top of the test file, I tried various things:

1. `jest.setMock("dotenv-safe", "../../mocks/dotenv-safe");`
   Doesn't work. The code being tested gets `"../../mocks/dotenv-safe.mock"` instead of a module.
2. `jest.mock("dotenv-safe", () => require("../../mocks/dotenv-safe"));`
   Doesn't work - The code being tested throws `TypeError: dotenvSafe.load is not a function`.
3. `jest.mock("dotenv-safe", () => { return { load: jest.fn(() => ({error: undefined, parsed: []})) }; });`
   Does work! But the mock is inline, and I want to move it to a separate file. I don't want to repeat this in every file.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require("../../mocks/dotenv-safe")` equals to module exports. It's default export that is used, so it should be:

```
jest.mock("dotenv-safe", () => require("../../mocks/dotenv-safe").default);
```

Comment: Wow! That one word made all the difference, and I spent hours on this trying every combination I found in the docs.

Comment: estus strikes again! They should call you "jestus" :)

Comment: There is also another way `jest.setMock("dotenv-safe", require("../../mocks/dotenv-safe"));`

Comment: @lonix Does it work? I'd expect the same thing with `default` to be applicable here, too.

Comment: Yes sorry the `default` is required - I changed my manual mock to `module.exports` format because it is less "surprising" in the consuming code (no need for `default`). My point was that there are two nice ways to do it, `jest.mock` and `jest.setMock`.